# Hibernate JPA hasOne mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Let's say we have two tables, `ORDERS` and `OFFERS`

**Order POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private @Id Integer id;
    private @NotNull @Email String ownerEmail;
    private @NotNull Integer offerId;
}
```

**Offer POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFERS")
public class Offer {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private @Id Integer id;
    private @Email @NotNull String ownerId;
}
```

Is it possible to fetch in single query on EntityManager `Order by ID` so that the result will contain related `Offer` object?

Like creating @Transient Offer field in Order, because we don't want to modify Offer data on persisting Order.

Or the only way is to create two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotating `@Transient` on the `offer` field in `Order` means that this field will be not mapped and persisted . Indeed ,  you should map this field but make it as read-only by setting its [@Column.insertable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#insertable%28%29) and [@Column.updatable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable%28%29) to false.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private @Id Integer id;
    private @NotNull @Email String ownerEmail;

    private @NotNull Integer offerId;

    @Column(insertable=false , updateable=false)
    private Offer offer;
}
```

To fetch the order along with its related offer in a single query , you can use the  fetch join :

```
SELECT order FROM Order order join fetch order.offer
```